# ¿Cómo convertir una llave (Fk) en sql server

Tags: sql-server

¿Cómo puedo convertir una llave (FK) con el tipo de dato varchar a int  en sql server?

Tengo el siguiente error 
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Este es el mensaje de error que me aparece :

> Mens. 1778, Nivel 16, Estado 0, Línea 2 El tipo de datos de la columna
>   'In_Producto.codigo' no coincide con el de la columna
>   'Servicios.id_Servicios' que hace la referencia en la clave externa
>   'FK__Servicios__id_Se__236943A5'. Mens. 1750, Nivel 16, Estado 0,
>   Línea 2 No se pudo crear la restricción. Consulte los errores
>   anteriores.

Comment: Bienvenida a StackOverflow Yesica. Sería de mucha ayuda si puedes editar tu pregunta para colocar el texto del error en lugar de una imagen que dificulta la lectura y análisis.

Comment: Las Fk deben tener el mismo tipo en las dos tablas, si no es así no se puede, ni se debe, ya que no se cumpliria la restricción. ¿Podrías agregar el diseño de ambas tablas y el código que ejecutas para que salga ese error?.

Comment: Hola Yesica. Como puedes ver, el mensaje de error te está diciendo cuál es el problema: los tipos de datos no coinciden. Lo que deberías hacer es eliminar la llave foránea, cambiar los tipos de datos en ambas tablas, y volver a crear la llave foránea.

Comment: Otra consulta, ¿Porque querés un FK entre un producto y un servicio?, no te estarás equivocando de columna?

Comment: Muchas gracias por sus aportes me fue de mucha ayuda, eran una de las opciones que tenia pero no están de mas tener otras opiniones DE NUEVO MUCHAS GRACIAS

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza, podrías copiar el comentario que has hecho como respuesta? De ese modo Yesica acepta la respuesta y seguimos creciendo en StackOverflow en Español!

Answer (score 0):

Buen día, [aquí](http://www.sql-server-helper.com/error-messages/msg-1778.aspx) de dejo la página de donde puedes hacer referencia para obtener más información. Ahora bien como se dice ahí:

> Este error se produce cuando se trata de crear una relación de
>   clave externa entre dos tablas y el tipo de datos de la columna de
>   referencia es diferente del tipo de datos de la clave primaria.

Esto significa que no puedes hacer una referencia entre dos columnas sí su tipo de dato son diferentes. La solución sería modificar los campos, para que queden del mismo tipo. Aquí te dejo un ejemplo de como alterar una columna

```
ALTER TABLE table_name
ALTER COLUMN column_name datatype
```

Answer (score 0):

Las fks solo se pueden crear entre dos tablas con el mismo tipo de dato, ya que la fk es que en la columna de la tabla hija solamente se puedan meter valores que ya están en una columna de la tabla madre, por esta razón deben de ser las dos columnas del mismo tipo.